# How do I remove a fill color when data gets entered in cells from an adjacent drop down list?

Tags: vba, excel

I created a macro that will populate multiple fields in a spreadsheet based on a drop-down selection, for example:

In column L, I have a drop down list of two items, "YES" and "NO". When an item is selected, the adjacent two cells will populate with predetermined data, for example:

Selecting "YES" will fill the two adjacent cells with yellow

Selecting "NO" will populate the two adjacent cells with the word, "NULL"

Here's where I am stuck..

When someone enters data in the adjacent two cells of "YES", I need the yellow fill to go away.

Is there a way to remove the yellow fill when someone enters data into such cells?

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Select Case Target

Case "YES"
    If Target = "YES" Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Target.Offset(0, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            If Not Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
                Exit Sub
                    If Intersect(Target, Columns(2)) Is Nothing Then
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
            End If
    End If
Case Else
    If Target = "NO" Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = "NULL"
        Target.Offset(0, 2) = "NULL"
            If Not Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
                Exit Sub
                    If Intersect(Target, Columns(2)) Is Nothing Then
                        Exit Sub
                            If Intersect(Target, Columns(2)) Is Nothing Then
                                Exit Sub
                            End If
                    End If
            End If
    End If
End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 If Target = "NO" Then
    Target.Offset(0, 1) = "NULL"
    Target.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
    Target.Offset(0, 2) = "NULL"
    Target.Offset(0, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
```

Comment: Thank you, @Cyril  this is what I needed, although when I clear the contents of a range of values, a run-time error '13': Type mismatch window appears. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: I don't believe I'm following what you mean.  How are you clearing contents?  I would imagine that you have an incorrect object, or the object type is incorrect.  if this answer has resolved the issue you posted for, then please mark as answered.  If you have any question, i can try to help, though please think if it's worth posting as another question (helps if I don't have an answer and others tend to check the newer posted items).

Comment: Forgot to @NickRivera for that last one.