# How do I remove the background color of a cell once a value or text is entered into that cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I created a macro for a data validation drop-down list that will populate cells in the adjacent two columns either with a value or with a yellow color fill depending on the selection. Below is a picture of how this looks:

[image]

When I enter data in the adjacent two cells after I select "YES" from the drop-down list, the yellow color fill remains in place. Below is a picture of how this looks:

[image]

Goal: I would like to have the yellow color fill *removed* or "unfilled" once any value or text gets entered in its cell.

Is there a way to do this in VBA? I am aware this is doable with conditional formatting, but I wanted to see whether this is doable in VBA.

Below is my code that I have drummed up:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If Target.Count > 1 Then Target.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub



Select Case Target

Case "YES"

    If Target = "YES" Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Target.Offset(0, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 6

         If Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = "NULL" Then Target.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
         If Target.Offset(0, 2).Value = "NULL" Then Target.Offset(0, 2).ClearContents

         If Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = "NULL" Then Target.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Pattern = xlNone

  If Target.Offset(0, 2).Value = "NULL" Then Target.Offset(0, 2).Interior.Pattern = xlNone

            If Not Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
                Exit Sub
            If Intersect(Target, Columns(2)) Is Nothing Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    End If
Case Else
    If Target = "NO" Then
       Target.Offset(0, 1) = "NULL"
       Target.Offset(0, 2) = "NULL"

       If Target.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then Target.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Pattern = xlNone

  If Target.Offset(0, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then Target.Offset(0, 2).Interior.Pattern = xlNone

            If Not Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
                Exit Sub
                    If Intersect(Target, Columns(2)) Is Nothing Then
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
            End If
    End If
End Select
End Sub
```

I would appreciate any help on this matter!

Comment: Why are you testing for intersect with 1Columns(2)1 when the changes you want to respond to are in Column 1?  I have many other questions...

Comment: There seems to be a little confusion in your code and an incorrectely used case statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought you had duplicated: [How do I remove a fill color when data gets entered in cells from an adjacent drop down list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46060706/how-do-i-remove-a-fill-color-when-data-gets-entered-in-cells-from-an-adjacent-dr/46060756#46060756)

Looks like you want conditional formatting, now, as opposed to just turning off the color.  You can either turn it on with Excel, or via VBA, similar to:

```
Sheets("NAME").Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
With Sheets("NAME").Range("B2:C10000")
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ISBLANK($B2),$A2=""Yes"")"
    With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
        .SetFirstPriority
        With .Interior
            .ColorIndex = 6
        End With
    End With
End With
```

This would replace your code completely for adding and removing color.

Comment: Note that I turn off conditional formatting BEFORE adding new, as the assumption is that no other conditional formatting exists.  The $before the column allows the formula to apply to all cells within the range, individually.  You would then take the other coloring out of the code, so that the conditional formatting would give it the yellow interior.

Comment: Thank you @Cyril for showing and explaining how to do this! I apologize for any confusion regarding the duplicate previous question. This question supersedes the previous duplicate question. Anyways, this seems to work properly now! I replaced my code completely for adding and removing the yellow color, which works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
'*** this assumes your yes no is in col A  and you potentially have data in col b and col c ***
'**declare your variables ***
Dim Check_Word As String
Dim Check_Data_ColB As String
Dim Check_Data_ColC As String


'** only run the code if something in col A B or C gets changed *****

If Target.Column = 1 Or Target.Column = 2 Or Target.Column = 3 Then

   '**** set check word to the value in col A ***
   Check_Word = Trim(UCase(Sh.Cells(Target.Row, 1).Text))
   '**** set check_data_colB to the value in col B ***
   Check_Data_ColB = Trim(Sh.Cells(Target.Row, 2).Text)
   '**** set check_data_colC to the value in col C ***
   Check_Data_ColC = Trim(Sh.Cells(Target.Row, 3).Text)

   '*** If the check word is NO or the check word is yes but there is text in col B or C then clear the cells colour ***
   If Check_Word = "NO" Or (Check_Word = "YES" And (Check_Data_ColB <> "" Or Check_Data_ColC <> "")) Then
     '*** all other situations result in the cells getting filled in with Yellow ****
     Sh.Cells(Target.Row, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
     Sh.Cells(Target.Row, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
   Else
     '*** all other situations result in the cells getting filled in with Yellow ****
     Sh.Cells(Target.Row, 2).Interior.Color = vbYellow
     Sh.Cells(Target.Row, 3).Interior.Color = vbYellow
   End If


End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @perfo I tested your code in lieu of mine.  When I enter data into the cells with the yellow fill (after I had selected "YES" from the drop-down list), the yellow fill doesn't get removed.

Comment: Sorry my code removes it with "NO" and fills it in with "YES" swap them around in the code and it should work....

Comment: I don't think I am following. Here's what I am trying to do: If I select "YES" from the drop-down list and enter data in the adjacent cells, then only the yellow fill will go away @perfo

Comment: THe above code has been modified so that it only clears a yellow cell if column A has NO in it or Column  A has YES but column B or Column C has text in...

Answer (score 0):

This sub will change the back fill with conditional formatting, you can just change the range to match what you want.
You can also do conditional formatting without any VBA, but I think this is what you want:

```
Sub FormatForValues()
Dim rngCells As Range
Set rngCells = Range("D9:D16")
    rngCells.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=LEN(TRIM(D9))>0"
rngCells.FormatConditions(rngCells.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With rngCells.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
   rngCells.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```